# Print numbers in diamond shape PHP

Tags: php, arrays

```
$arr = array(1,2,4,7,12,17,21,24,26,27);
for($i=1; $i<count($arr); $i++) {
    for($j=$arr[$i-1]; $j<$arr[$i]; $j++) {
        echo $j;
    }
    echo "<br>";
}
```

I am trying to use for loops to make a shape that looks like the diamond shape . at this time it's look like half diamond shape.

i want to help in this .

Comment: Do you want a diamond outline or a fully filled in diamond?  In either case, you'll need a monospaced font to ensure proportions.

Comment: @Anthony, I think he's referring to ASCII shapes.

Comment: @anthony i want the diamond outline.

Comment: So my solution is a filled in diamond. That's not the goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the best I could come up with:

```
echo '<pre style="text-align:center;">';
$arr = array(1,2,4,7,12,17,21,24,26,27);
for($i=1; $i<count($arr); $i++) {
    for($j=$arr[$i-1]; $j<$arr[$i]; $j++) {
        echo $j;
    }
    echo "<br>";
}
```

So what you want is (without the shape):

```
      1
     2  4
 7  12  17  21 
    24  26
      27
```

I'm having trouble getting where the lines break, since the numbers in the array don't come out to a "symmetrical" number.

Or do you want this:

```
       1 
      2  4
     7    12
    17     21 
     24   26
        27
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

$kk=25;
$m=1;
for($kkk=1;$kkk<=7;$kkk++)
{
        for($k=0;$k<=$kk;$k++)
        {
            echo ('&nbsp;');
        }

        for($j=1; $j<=$m; $j++)
        {

            echo $j;
        }
            $kk=$kk-1 ;
            echo "<br>";
            $m=$m+2;

}



?>
```

full diamond

```
<?php

$kk=25;
$m=1;
for($kkk=1;$kkk<=5;$kkk++)
{
        for($k=0;$k<=$kk;$k++)
        {
            echo ('&nbsp;');
        }

        for($j=1; $j<=$m; $j++)
        {

            echo $j;
        }
            $kk=$kk-1 ;
            echo "<br>";
            $m=$m+2;

}

$kk=22;
$m=9;
for($kkk=1;$kkk<=5;$kkk++)
{
        for($k=1;$k<=$kk;$k++)
        {
            echo ('&nbsp;');
        }

        for($j=$m; $j>=1; $j--)
        {

            echo $j;
        }
            $kk=$kk+1 ;
            echo "<br>";
            $m=$m-2;

}




?>
```

Comment: That gets me a pyramid, not a diamond.  Is that the goal?

Answer (score 1):

```
    <?php
echo '<div style="text-align:center;">';
$jeff = "5";
$y=1;
for($x=1;$x<=$jeff+1;$x++){
    for($y=1;$y<$x;$y++)
        {
        echo"*";
        }
        echo"<br>";
}
$rey = $jeff-1;
for($x=$rey;$x>=1;$x--){
    for($y=1;$y<$x;$y++)
        {
        echo"*";
        }
        echo"<br>";
}
echo"</div>"
?>
```

Comment: most simplest i think, the value of variable $jeff will be the center of the diamond